# Receiving "Pending" notifications from running Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm near the end of Chapter 5 on Hartl's Tutorial. In the previous section (5.4), I have created a user signup page. Now I am required to check that I have created the user signup static page correctly by running rspec:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/
```

and I get this notice:

```
Pending:
  StaticPagesHelper add some examples to (or delete) /Users/kelvinyu/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/helpers/static_pages_helper_spec.rb
    # No reason given
    # ./spec/helpers/static_pages_helper_spec.rb:12
  static_pages/help.html.erb sample
    # No reason given
    # ./spec/views/static_pages/help.html.erb_spec.rb:4
  static_pages/home.html.erb add some examples to (or delete) /Users/kelvinyu/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/views/static_pages/home.html.erb_spec.rb
    # No reason given
    # ./spec/views/static_pages/home.html.erb_spec.rb:4

Finished in 0.28953 seconds
16 examples, 0 failures, 3 pending

Randomized with seed 27698
```

Not sure what this "Pending" status really means and if I have an error. If so, what is the best way to fix this? Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pending means that the example is not yet implemented or finished.

In your case it means you need 3 more examples to implement.

How can you mark examples as pending? Usually you just omit the block when defining example (via *it* method). Or you can use the *pending* method. More information you can find [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/pending/pending-examples).

Answer (score 0):

Those are the just the tests that are auto-generated along with the spec files when you create a model or controller.  They're basically just placeholders until you create your own tests.

You're safe to (and should) delete them.

Answer (score 0):

In recent Rails, newly generated controller spec includes the `skip` command, which will pend the test too.